# IHttpHandler null session (on some servers)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis-7, ihttphandler

I have an IHttpHandler that implements IRequiresSessionState. Everything works fine on most servers but there are 2 servers (one IIS 7.0 and one IIS 7.5) that give me null sessions. Aspx pages are fine on every server. I've searched for hours and failed to find anything that is not related to IRequiresSessionState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by making sure you also register your handler under the system.webserver element of your web.config:

And access the session object using HttpContext.Current.Session.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
...
using System.Web.SessionState;
public class Data : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{

    var b = context.Session["data"]; 
    ...
    ...
}
```